# How could I get all strings from .elf file?

Tags: elf, disassembly, ctf

I have a [file](https://ctforces.informatics.ru/media/files/pochtalyon_0e0e9e17feda4eb7b91a4068ae76e198) and [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/4140f3cc8b7623552beabe57fe0e0bda5efa038da21561b56e46c8ded7195f76/detection) (from one of "Shadow CTF" contests) that have a few strings in it.

I used IDA to get all the strings, but I get only "error" string. I have already tried hex editing this file but that gave nothing.

I am a beginner at disassembling.

Comment: `$ strings <filename>`. [man strings](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strings)